# Using C#6 string interpolation like String.Format

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

Is it possible in C#6 to somehow use string interpolation similary like `String.Format(format, params object[] args)`?

In another words, is it possible that string interpolation like this:

```
string name = "John";
string greetings = $"Hello {name}";
Console.WriteLine(greetings); //outputs "Hello John"
```

could be called like this?

```
string name = "John";
string template = "Hello {name}";
string greetings = String.Csharp6Interpolation(template, name);
Console.WriteLine(greetings); //outputs "Hello John"
```

It doesn't have to look exactly like this, I'm just curious whether it is simply possible to invoke the string interpolation proceduraly and not via the dollar sign in $"Hello {name}".

Comment: "There is no current mechanism provided by the framework to evaluate interpolated strings at runtime." ... nevermind then :)